# Is Oxide Anion more stable than O^+

Tags: ions, stability

O likes to be negative if charged at all. Most metal oxides are of the form $\ce{A^{x+} O^{2-}_{x/2}}$ (where $x$ is the magnitude of the positive charge and $\ce{A}$ is a metal.) Here, despite the $\ce{O}$ preferring covalent bonds it most often forms ionic bonds because of how metals behave and EN difference.

There are some compounds that have $\ce{O^+}$ in them. Hydronium is an example of that. When the O is positively charged the ions form a cation complex which itself is in a complex of ions and so on and so forth. This is why $\ce{H3O+}$ isn't really $\ce{H3O+}$ as individual ions but rather a complex formed from $\ce{H3O+}$ ions spreading the positive charge across all positively charged oxygen atoms.

Is the oxide anion despite being really reactive more stable than the $\ce{O^+}$ ion since in the oxide anion the $\ce{O}$ already has an octet and it is negatively charged which is what $\ce{O}$ prefers?

Comment: You have a very rare view of this situation. Most people would say that $O^{-2}$ is very stable and unreactive, but will attach itself to positively charged ions due to the attraction of unlike charges. Reactivity is use to indicate how likely an atom (or ion) will react and change it oxidation state.

Comment: Well if you were to form from NaOH(aq) O^2-(which would require if you want it to stay aqueous superheating of the H2O(heating past boiling point without boiling))  than that would steal 2 protons from 1 water molecule forming another O^2- and so on until it reached the Na+ and then form Na2O which is the most common of all sodium oxides. Thus my saying that the oxide anion is very reactive.

Comment: $Na_2O$ would only form after all the water evaporated. But I don't see how you envision a water molecule losing an electron (or 2). I have never heard anyone mention $H_2O^+$.

Comment: I edited my comment to say "2 protons" once I realized my mistake. The Ion Pair effect is what makes some ionic compounds not completely disassociate in water. I think that Na2O is one of those that has a really strong Ion Pair effect(definitely stronger than NaCl) and so doesn't completely disassociate into 2 Na+ and O^2-. Calcium flouride also doesn't completely disassociate into Ca^2+ and 2 F- because of the Ion Pair effect.

Comment: and how do you know without the amount of positive charge in the metal known that in a metal oxide there would be the charge divided by 2 for the number of oxygen atoms?